# ¿Cómo hacer un extracto incremental en tableau que sea actualizable?

Tags: base-de-datos, datatables, etl

Tableau Desktop permite realizar cargas incrementales desde la edición del extracto donde se configura un campo para que marque el punto de control de lo que ya se cargó y lo que falta.
La primera vez hace una carga full o completa y luego comienzan las cargas incrementales.
El campo para el control incremental debe determinar específicamente qué se va a cargar.
A partir de dicho campo se traen las novedades. Lo que se determine como *"nuevo"*.

---

### ¿Pero qué pasa si un dato se actualiza, si un registro tiene modificaciones?

Si el registro entra como novedad uno supone que pisaría o sobrescribiría el registro existente.
 *Pero esto no sucede.*
*Lo que sucede es que entra otro registro con los mismos identificadores pero como un registro "nuevo".*
O sea, quedan dos registros similares dentro de Tableau.
Tableau no tiene "update". Solo agrega registros con el extracto incremental.
**¿Podemos resolver esto con Tableau Desktop o Tableau Server para poder tener esas actualizaciones con carga incremental y aprovechar la ventaja de no cargar todo permanentemente?**

Dejo dos notas de Tableau donde hace referencia:
[Extraer datos](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/es-es/extracting_data.htm) donde dice "... de efectuar una actualización incremental, que solo añade las filas nuevas desde la última actualización..."

[Refresco de datos](https://tps://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/es-es/extracting_refresh.htm): "...En lugar de actualizar toda la extracción, puede configurar una actualización para que solo se añadan las filas que sean nuevas desde la última vez que extrajo los datos..."

***How to make an incremental extract in Tableau that is upgradeable?***

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurrió una forma para obtener los datos modificados y tener acceso solo al último registro.
Lo pensé como versión del registro. Esto puede tener más utilidades también y resultó ser funcional al problema planteado.
Básicamente utilizar funciones dentro del propio tableau para determinar cuál es la versión del registro y aplicarla como filtro del extracto.
**Hago una simulación con SQL y Tableau Desktop.**

Esta simulación la utilizamos con Tableau Server y funcionó de manera programada.
Espero les sirva para resolver éste asunto que cuando los volúmenes de datos son grandes está claro que el extracto incremental cambia los tiempos de forma sustancial.
Si a alguien le interesa puedo cargar unas imágenes de cómo hacerlo. Saludos

```
----- Simulación de Carga Incremental de Tableau desde SQL Server -----
--- Ir por partes para observar como funciona ---
Create Table TestSimulaIncremental (
TicketID int
, Contenido varchar(80)
, TicketFechaCrea datetime2 default (getdate())
, TicketFechaModi datetime2 default (getdate())
) 
--- Carga Inicial -- Ponemos como si hubiesen entrado todos a las 0hs del día.
Declare @Ahora datetime2 = getdate()-1
Insert Into TestSimulaIncremental (TicketID, Contenido, TicketFechaCrea, TicketFechaModi)
Values (1, 'Prueba 1er ticket', @Ahora, @Ahora)
, (2, 'Segundo va', @Ahora, @Ahora)
, (3, 'Parece que funciona', @Ahora, @Ahora)
, (4, 'otra vez', @Ahora, @Ahora)
, (5, 'Sí, esto va...', @Ahora, @Ahora)
--- Cargamos Nuestro Tableau de Simulación.
--- Observamos los resultados en SQL y Tableau 
Select * From TestSimulaIncremental
--- Configuramos carga Incremental en Tableau por TicketFechaModi
--- Reiniciamos carga y revisamos nuevamente. Quedaron 5 registros.
--- Cargamos 1 registro de prueba, como si fuera una transacción nueva
Insert Into TestSimulaIncremental (TicketID, Contenido)
Values (6, 'Ticket luego de configurar incremental')
--- Actualiza fuente Tableau (ya con carga incremental)
--- Revisamos nuevamente Tableau y SQL. Quedaron 6 registros. 1 con fecha de modi más nueva.
--- Revisamos historial de actualizaciones de Tableau y se ven 2 cargas, la 1ra con cinco registros la 2da con uno.
--- Modificamos un registro como si fuera una transacción que modifica
Update TestSimulaIncremental 
Set Contenido = 'Otra vez, ¿y si lo modificamos?'
    , TicketFechaModi = Getdate() 
Where TicketID = 4
--- Actualiza fuente Tableau 
--- Revisamos nuevamente Tableau y SQL.
Select * From TestSimulaIncremental Order by TicketFechaModi desc
--- Ahora hay 7 registros en Tableau y se observan las nuevas fechas de modif y en SQL hay 6.
--- ¿Qué?, ¿Cómo?
--- Sí, efectivamente, hay 7 registros en Tableau, o sea que la modificación entra como un nuevo registro.
--- ¿Entonces?
--- Aquí comienza la magia. Bueno, en realidad no es magia.
--- Tenemos 6 en SQL y 7 en Tableau. 
--- Si leemos "entre líneas" podríamos decir que el 7mo es una nueva versión del Id 4. 
--- Revisamos historial de actualizaciones de Tableau y se ven 3 cargas, la 1ra con cinco registros la 2da con 1 y la 3ra con 1.
--- Funciones en Tableau. Vamos a crear dos funciones en Tableau que nos permitirán mostrar únicamente la última versión del registro.
--- Aquí alguien quizás va intuyendo el truco.
--- TicketFechaModi Ultima Modi y Actual
--- VersionUltima: {FIXED TicketID : MAX([TicketFechaModi]) }
--- VersionActiva: IF [VersionUltima] = [TicketFechaModi] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
--- Por último podemos simular una inserción y modificación más para empezar a creer que funciona.
Update TestSimulaIncremental
Set Contenido = 'Ahora el 2 quedó modificado'
   , TicketFechaModi = Getdate() 
Where TicketID = 2
Insert Into TestSimulaIncremental (TicketID, Contenido, TicketFechaModi)
Values (1, 'Prueba 1er ticket', getdate())
```

Comment: Decidí cargar esta solución porque muchas veces encontré soluciones en la web, desde los bbs hasta hoy y alguna vez quise publicar y por alguna razón no pude. Ahora decidí hacerlo para aportar algo a la comunidad de la que nos alimentamos todes. Salud!